# Embedded Linux: No output from date when stdout directed to file or FIFO

Tags: linux, date, busybox

I am trying to pass the date into a file e.g.:

`/pwd # date > file.txt`

but every time I check the file, nothing is printed in there. I have tried other variants as well e.g.:

`/pwd # echo "$(date)" > file.txt`

`/pwd # echo "$(/bin/date)" > /full/path/file.txt`

`/pwd # echo "$(/bin/date)" >> /full/path/file.txt` (I wouldn't expect appending to make a difference but tried anyway)

I thought well maybe it was some sort of permissions issue with `date` being able to access the file so, for kicks, I tried:

`/pwd # sudo date > /full/path/file.txt`

Attempting to store the date to bash variable is futile as well. But, sure enough, the `date` command by itself continues to work:

`Mon Apr  5 14:16:26 UTC 2021`

Anyone have any ideas what could be happening? According to every other post I've read, the things I am trying should be working.

Note this is a special (proprietary) kernel (`uname -a`):

[image]

However it's built on Debian so I would expect it to work.

EDIT:
`type date`:

`date is a tracked alias for /bin/date`

Nothing interesting happens when prefixing command with `set -x` other than the tracking I see when running the command:

[image]

`strace` looks like it has some good information but I won't pretend to know how to interpret it:

[image]

EDIT 2:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me under `Linux nkclintjs 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 25 20:13:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (CentOS 7)

Comment: What does `type date` return? (That'll tell us if your `date` command is shadowed by an alias/function/etc). If you run `set -x` before the command, anything interesting/surprising?

Comment: One way to take any chance of system-specific peculiarities out of the picture would be to build a Dockerfile that reproduces the problem. If the issue can only be reproduced on your own system and somewhere else, that makes this more of a system administration question, and those aren't generally topical here; so it's important to figure out how to build a [mre] that reproduces it on someone else's machine.

Comment: Another thing you can look at is `strace date >/full/path/file.txt`, to get a full trace of execution. If there's no longer a bug when run that way, that implies that taking your shell out of the picture was pertinent -- presumably `type` or `set -x` will also show something odd if used as suggested above.

Comment: BTW, in `sudo somecommand >outfile`, opening `outfile` happens _before_ `sudo` happens, and long before `somecommand` can happen. Thus, `sudo` doesn't change the permissions available for the open operation at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for all the quick hints. I will address your questions in EDIT to original post

Comment: BTW, `set +x` will turn off the tracing that `set -x` enables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please see original post for answers to your questions/hints

Comment: wrt. strace, we _should_ see a line like `write(1, "Mon 05 Apr 2021 04:26:59 CDT\n", 32) = 32` showing the `date` command asking the OS to perform a write to stdout on its behalf.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right before `close(3)` you mean?

Comment: ...that `io_submit` is unusual -- it's an asynchronous syscall, whereas `write()` is synchronous. I'm really curious how your glibc is compiled, to be using async I/O tools even for synchronous writes.

Comment: No, not before `close(3)` -- that's a read of `/etc/localtime`, that's completely normal.

Comment: Which architecture is this?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `uname -a` indicates `armv4tl`

Comment: ...btw, as a general note, [textual transcripts are strongly preferred over images here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122).

Comment: what is output of `id -a; ls -ld .; ls -l file.txt; rm -f file.txt; ls -l file.txt; touch file.txt; ls -l file.txt` ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would but don't have copy/paste capability to my client (I am remote accessing the machine)

Comment: So, if I were going to dig into this, I'd look into the local libc's behavior to figure out why it's trying to use async I/O syscalls; but I'd want access to the actual binaries, a debugger (whether local or remote) and a system able to run them to do that investigation -- it's more an on-the-clock investigation than something that makes sense to do here.

Comment: ...as a hunch, though -- and this certainly may not go anywhere -- is behavior any different with unbuffered stdout? If you have a `stdbuf` command, does `stdbuf  -o0 date` behave any differently?

Comment: @jhnc Pleese see EDIT 2 in original post

Comment: BTW, "tracked alias" is ksh terminology; this shouldn't be tagged or titled as bash if you're using ksh (not that it'll make any difference, the shell and `date` are on two different sides of an execve boundary, so `date` will generally behave the same way no matter which shell invokes it)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `/bin/sh: stdbuf: not found` (assuming understood your instructions correctly). So I thought that I might not be in bash (and that it was the source of my problem) so I created an sh file with the bash shebang to execute my commands but had same result

Comment: @CharlesDuffy are there any workarounds you think? I literally just need to pass the date/time into the file - I don't actually care how its achieved

Comment: _nod_, `stdbuf` is part of modern GNU coreutils, but older systems won't have it, and systems using an alternate set of tools like busybox may or may not.

Comment: If you _do_ have a newer version of bash, it has built-in functionality equivalent to date you can use instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, can you explain the application of your last comment?

Comment: ever since... maybe bash 4.3 or so?... f/e, you should be able to run `printf '%(%c)T' -1 >outfile`. But you need to run that with bash, not sh, and it needs to be a quite modern version of bash.

Comment: ...you can start bash and run `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to see which version you actually have.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy bash version: 3.1.17(1)-release

Comment: that all looks fine. one final test I forgot: `echo hello > file.txt; ls -l file.txt; od -c file.txt`

Comment: 3.1.17 is _much_ (more than a decade) too old to have `printf %()T`. I don't have a workaround for you there.

Comment: I don't suppose you have `expect` installed? If so, `unbuffer date` will fake a TTY, and can make software behave more like it does when writing to the terminal when stdout is to a non-terminal destination.

Comment: @jhnc see last picture in original post

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well thanks anyway for your help - no I don't have `expect`

Comment: Out of curiosity at this point: Mind if I ask what the hardware is? I don't usually see questions about 10-year-old (presumably) embedded systems running almost-15-year-old kernels.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy https://docs.embeddedarm.com/TS-7390

Comment: well, it certainly seems specific to the date command, and not a general permission issue. I presume it makes no difference to do: `/bin/date > file.txt` ?

Comment: @jhnc thats correct

Comment: armv4t is supported in buildroot. If I wanted to build a modern software stack for that hardware, I'd probably start there.

Comment: @jhnc, ...the use of async I/O sticks out like a sore thumb to me -- if you look at `strace`, date isn't doing anything to actually make sure the write has finished before it exits. I'm hard-pressed to read this as anything but a libc bug, assuming this is the same GNU `date` everyone else uses and not a creaky busybox build or such (which is probably worth validating).

Comment: @SterlingButters, ...on that latter point, does `date --version` give you a version number or a usage error? If the latter, it's presumably a non-GNU implementation.

Comment: @SterlingButters, ...also, at this point, if just building a whole new software image is incompatible with the work you're trying to accomplish, I'd be starting to look at other tools available on the system. Have a Python interpreter? Easy enough to get a date in there, and that way if you need to add logic (like an explicit flush) to work around the OS and libc being weird, you're in a place to do it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah I get `date: invalid option -- v` and there is no python. This kernel is __incredibly__ minimized

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wow... I do have perl though

Comment: It's not the kernel but the userland being minimal that's hurting us here -- nothing we're dealing with is kernel functionality (well, the syscalls are, but it's userland deciding which ones to use and how to use them).

Comment: ...but yes, I think it's probably time to write some perl (ugh; it hurts even saying that).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy LOL yes, I only touched perl once - briefly... VERY briefly. I may request to the manufacturer that they look into this as well but I appreciate all your help in the meantime anyway

Comment: They're still shipping and supporting this software stack today? That's scary -- this is a decade worth of security updates not present.

Comment: In a past life, I worked for [a company that built and maintained a Linux distro specifically for embedded systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MontaVista). There are good reasons having an up-to-date, actively-maintained software stack is worth paying for. :)

Comment: `perl -e '$|=1; print scalar localtime, "\n"' > file.txt`

Comment: @jhnc That works! Thanks! You and Charles should share an accepted answer

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I assume so - or the vendor was sitting on the hardware forever until it actually got used... But I agree - not ideal

Comment: @CharlesDuffy link says `Standard Linux utilities are provided by the busybox program. Type 'help' for a list of provided utilities. Source code for the busybox utility is available on the Technologic Systems FTP site. ` so could probably work out exactly what's happening if the version is known by checking [the source](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/) (or https://files.embeddedarm.com/ts-arm-sbc/ts-7390-linux/sources/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unusual situation -- from the strace results, it looks like either a libc bug or a busybox problem. Since this is a decade-old software stack, you don't have the recently-introduced date formatting `printf` builtin bash added in 4.3.

The easiest workaround is to not use the busybox date command at all, and instead to switch to a scripting language -- Python, Perl, etc. [@jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971581/jhnc) was kind enough to provide a perl command for the purpose:

```sh
perl -e '$|=1; print scalar localtime, "\n"' > file.txt
```